# Как скопировать window.location.href в буфер обмена?

Tags: javascript, vue3, buffer

Пишу проект на Vue3 есть кнопка при её нажатии window.location.href должен копироваться в буфер обмена. Почитал в интернете можно это реализовать с помощью фальшивого input . Но все примеры в интернете используют статичный value . Я пытаюсь передавать ему window.location.href , но в буфер эти данные не копируются. Вот input и функция.
Помогите пожалуйста в чём проблема ?

```
 <input
    type="text"
    id="myInput"
    :value="copyTextInput"
    style="display:none;"
    ref="copyInput"
  />
  const copyTextInput = ref();
  const copyInput = ref();
  const copyToClipBoard = () => {
      copyTextInput.value = window.location.href;
      copyInput.value.select();
      document.execCommand("copy");
      alert("Copied the text: " + copyTextInput.value);
   };
```

Answer (score 1):

Input должен отображаться на экране. display:none ломает вам малину.
Спрячьте input за пределами экрана